# Select para ordenar por hora

Tags: mysql

Boa tarde Pessoal, preciso fazer um select que organize por data e hora. Por data já está funcionando, porém se eu colocar um "and" "hora" depois do data, bagunça todos os registros. Vejam meu select:

```
$dados = Connection::select("Select *,id, data, mes,date_format(`data`,'%d/%m/%Y') as `data_formatada` FROM (SELECT Day(data) AS dia, year(data) AS ano,    
                    (CASE month(data) 
                       when 1 then 'Janeiro'
                       when 2 then 'Fevereiro'
                       when 3 then 'Março'
                       when 4 then 'Abril'
                       when 5 then 'Maio'
                       when 6 then 'Junho'
                       when 7 then 'Julho'
                       when 8 then 'Agosto'
                       when 9 then 'Setembro'
                       when 10 then 'Outubro'
                       when 11 then 'Novembro'
                       when 12 then 'Dezembro'
                       END) AS mes,
                    (CASE WEEKDAY(data) 
                       when 0 then 'Segunda-feira'
                       when 1 then 'Terça-feira'
                       when 2 then 'Quarta-feira'
                       when 3 then 'Quinta-feira'
                       when 4 then 'Sexta-feira'
                       when 5 then 'Sábado'
                       when 6 then 'Domingo'                 
                       END) AS DiaDaSemana,
                       id, 
                       data,hora,compromisso,pessoa,local FROM agenda WHERE not (data is null)) as agenda order by data asc"
```

Comment: Fica difícil saber o que é "bagunça", veja [como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: o seu campo data é um timestamp? com data e hora?

Comment: Não, são separados, o campo data é "date" e o campo hora é "time".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O comando ORDER BY aceita multiplos parametros:

```
ORDER BY campo1 ASC, campo2 ASC
```

Então sua consulta ficaria:

```
$dados = Connection::select("
        Select 
            *,
            date_format(`data`,'%d/%m/%Y') as `data_formatada` 
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                Day(data) AS dia, 
                year(data) AS ano,
                (
                    CASE month(data) 
                       when 1 then 'Janeiro'
                       when 2 then 'Fevereiro'
                       when 3 then 'Março'
                       when 4 then 'Abril'
                       when 5 then 'Maio'
                       when 6 then 'Junho'
                       when 7 then 'Julho'
                       when 8 then 'Agosto'
                       when 9 then 'Setembro'
                       when 10 then 'Outubro'
                       when 11 then 'Novembro'
                       when 12 then 'Dezembro'
                   END) AS mes,
                (
                    CASE WEEKDAY(data) 
                       when 0 then 'Segunda-feira'
                       when 1 then 'Terça-feira'
                       when 2 then 'Quarta-feira'
                       when 3 then 'Quinta-feira'
                       when 4 then 'Sexta-feira'
                       when 5 then 'Sábado'
                       when 6 then 'Domingo'                 
                       END
                    ) AS DiaDaSemana,
                id, 
                data,
                hora,
                compromisso,
                pessoa,
                local 
            FROM 
                agenda
            WHERE 
                not (data is null)
        ) as agenda

        ORDER BY
            data ASC, 
            hora ASC");
```

Comment: Humm, eu tava colocando AND. Funcionou. Obrigado.

Comment: @Eduehi, Sua consulta estava um pouco desorganizada, talvez seja por isso que você não encontrou o erro, pois realmente era algo bem simples. Caso precise organizar consultas SQL de forma eficaz, existem ferramentas online que pode estar fazendo isso para você [http://www.sql-format.com], [http://sqlformat.org], talves isso possa estar lhe auxiliando no futuro.